# Is there an example of index 1 picardnumber 1 Fano 4-fold with h^{21}\neq0

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Are there any known examples of index 1 smooth Fano 4-folds X with $\mathsf{Pic}(X)\cong\mathbb{Z}$  with $h^2(\Omega^1_X)\neq0$?

Comment: Did you already try complete intersections of theta divisors in a moduli space of principal $G$-bundles ($G semisimple) on a smooth, projective curve?  The weight 1 Hodge structure of the curve induces a weight 3 Hodge structure of the moduli space, which maps to the weight 3 Hodge structure of the complete intersection.